# Ruby syntax in method calls arguments

Tags: ruby, syntax

I came across some Ruby code like this:

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
 end
```

I understand:

1. `create_table` is a function and we are calling it with some arguments
2. first argument is a string `"articles"`
3. A block is passed to the function after `force: :cascade`

I can't figure out what `force: :cascade` is. Can someone explain what `force: :cascade` is?

Comment: `force: :cascade` is shorthand for `:force => :cascade`, which is shorthand for `{ :force => :cascade }`.

Comment: It's a instance of Hash class, where the key is :force and the value is :cascade, both instances of Symbol class.

Comment: If you had `def m(x, h); puts x; puts h; end`, `m(1, a: 1, b: 2)` would print `1` then `{:a=>1, :b=>2}`. See [this article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments) about *keyword arguments*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `create_table` is a function and we are calling it with some arguments

No. `create_table` is a *message* that is being sent to a *receiver*. In this case, the message send doesn't mention an explicit receiver, in which case the implicit receiver is always `self`.

A message send, in turn, will typically lead to an invocation of a *method* of the same name. (In other languages, *message sends* are called *method calls* for that reason.)

There are no functions in Ruby.

> I can't figure out what `force: :cascade` is. Can someone explain what `force: :cascade` is?

You actually can't know by only looking at the arguments of the message send. It could be either a *keyword argument* or a *`Hash` literal positional argument*.

*Keyword arguments* allow you to pass arguments to a message send via a name instead of a position (as *positional arguments* do). This means that you can pass keyword arguments in any order, and it means that you can leave out *any* optional argument, whereas with positional arguments, you can only leave out optional arguments from the end.

*`Hash` literal positional arguments* are a bit of syntactic sugar that allows you to leave out the curly braces if the very last argument of a message send is a `Hash` literal. They were originally intended to act as a substitute for keyword arguments.

As I wrote above, you cannot tell just from the message send whether it is a keyword argument or a `Hash` literal positional argument. We actually have to look at the *parameter list* of the *method* to see what the *argument list* of the *message* means. (Note: this is unique to `Hash` literal positional arguments and keyword arguments, normally you can tell what an argument list means without looking at the parameter list. This ambiguity is due to the fact that `Hash` literal positional arguments were originally intended as substitutes for keyword arguments, and then keyword arguments were added in a way that tries to be backwards-compatible with `Hash` literal positional arguments.)

In older versions of Ruby on Rails, the method is defined like this:

```
create_table(table_name, options = {})
```

So, this means that `force: :cascade` is an optional `Hash` literal positional argument which gets bound to the optional parameter `options`.

However, in Ruby on Rails 5, the definition looks like this:

```
create_table(table_name, comment: nil, **options)
```

Which means that `force: :cascade` is a keyword argument that gets bound as part of the `**options` keyword splat parameter. (A *keyword splat parameter* acts for keyword arguments like a positional splat parameter acts for positional arguments; it collects all "leftover" keyword arguments in a `Hash` the same way a positional splat parameter collects all "leftover" positional arguments in an `Array`.)

So, the answer to your question what `force: :cascade` is in the code snippet you posted is actually dependent on which version of Ruby on Rails (or more precisely ActiveRecord) you use: it is either a *keyword argument* or a *`Hash` literal positional argument*.

*Only* in the latter case, i.e. *only if you use an older version of Ruby on Rails* is it equivalent to

```
create_table("articles", { force: :cascade }) do |t|
```

In Ruby on Rails 5, you would be trying to pass two positional arguments to a method that only accepts one.

Answer (score 0):

If you check how `create_table` is defined you'll see

```
create_table(table_name, options = {}) public
```

so `"articles"` is a `table_name` and `force: :cascade` is `options`, in other words it's equal to

```
create_table("articles", {force: :cascade}) do
  ...
end
```

depending on the version of Rails you use, method signature will differ

```
create_table(table_name, comment: nil, **options) # Rails 5 and later
create_table(table_name, options = {})            # Before Rails 5
```